# How to take nth-child in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to select :nth-child() for all the elements in html except last element.

Is this valid=

```
  td:nth-child:not(last-child){

    //Some css//
    }
```

I am using text-overflow:ellipsis property to hide overflow from table in `<td>` elements.

It got successful with using `even`,`odd` children of this `<td>`.
I want this ellipsis effects in all td blocks except last child of table.

I've given it a try-

```
.table-condensed tbody tr  td:nth-child:not(last-child) a
 {
     white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

But that's is not a trick obviously. Any suggestions?

Comment: dont mean to be a bitch, but why wont you adjust the style to the first 4 of them, and then change the last one to the one you wan

Comment: Can you clarify? You want all `<td>s` except the last in every row? Or you want all `<td>s` except those in the last row?

Comment: @billyonecan style in each td element except last td

Comment: Is it not possible for you to just add a class to the last `<td>`? I don't think there's an existing selector which meets your requirements

Comment: @billyonecan, i don't know the reason that why didn't you understand my question!

Answer (score 4):

Little bit long-winded, but should do the trick:

```
tr:not(:last-child) > td, tr:last-child > td:not(:last-child) {
    // styles
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBxAW/)

Comment: Hehe, nice solution (same as I got after some playing around, but no point duplicating the answer). Just remember it's for styling the `a` elements, so it would be more like `tr:not(:last-child) > td a, tr:last-child > td:not(:last-child) a { }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `td:not(:last-child)` as part of your selector, and it will match every cell except the last in each row.

**[Similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/dtdsF/)**.

I don't understand at all why you have included a bare `:nth-child` in your selector -- what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I think the OP wanted every `<td>` but the very last one (not the last of each row - though I could be mistaken)

Comment: @billyonecan: I see you have already supplied a solution for that case, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the CSS style of the last child:

```
td:last-child a {
   text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an XY problem. You can't directly apply a style to all `nth-child` elements except the `last-child`, but you can use two styles:

```
.table-condensed tbody tr td a {
     white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.table-condensed tbody tr  td:last-child a {
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```